# jQuery Multiselect filter conflicts with single select

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-multiselect

http://jsfiddle.net/rH2K6/ <-- Single Select works fine here.

```
$("select").multiselect({
multiple: false, 
    click: function(event, ui){
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d3CLM/ <-- Single Select breaks here (reverts to multiselect) because I apply the filter plugin!

So, what I need is a single select widget with filter. Can anyone help me out here please?

Thanks!

PS: The fiddle somehow does not show the filter, but you get the point here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work (pass the 'multiple' option to the `multiselect` function):

```
$("select").multiselect({
    multiple: false
}).multiselectfilter({
    click: function (event, ui) {
        // click-handler    
    }
});
```

(see: http://jsfiddle.net/d3CLM/3/)

Comment: Nice ;). Please consider accepting this answer, thanks.